# Automation facebook create post in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

So, I'm trying to make an automation that create a post in post, For example here in this image. I would like to post randomly or click that to show the pop-up "Create a post" and then send keys there...however I don't know why it doesn't click or send keys I already check the elements in chrome dev tools to check the elements

[starting post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEfur.png)[Pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s91TL.png)

I'm using a python code here...but I don't know how cause it keeps saying the error of this one.

```
"Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//span[contains(text(), 'What's on your mind, Myth?')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/span[contains(text(), 'What's on your mind, Myth?')]' is not a valid XPath expression."
```

And this is the code...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import random
import string
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Create a webdriver object for Chrome and set the window size
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.set_window_size(1200, 800)

auto_link = 'https://facebook.com/'

driver.get(auto_link)




email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='email']")
password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='pass']")
# login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='u_0_5_jA']")
login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "./html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button")

# //*[@id="mount_0_0_jy"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]
# //*[@id="scrollview"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span
# /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span
# email
# //*[@id="email"]
email.click()
email.send_keys("xxxxxx")

#pass
# //*[@id="pass"]
password.click()
password.send_keys("XXXXX")

login_button.click()

# Click on the "What's on your mind" button
whats_on_your_mind_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(text(), 'What\'s on your mind, Myth?')]")
whats_on_your_mind_button.click()

time.sleep(1000)



driver.quit()
```

And the thing that I'm expecting here to happen is that I can post after that...

Comment: When using double quotes ("") for the actual string, no need to the single quite. Or you can escape properly the string with double quotes Ex: ".//span[contains(text(), \"What's on your mind, Myth?\")]"

Comment: @Infern0 it doesn't change anything..the error still the same 

`Exception has occurred: InvalidSelectorException
Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//span[contains(text(), 'What's on your mind, Myth?')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/span[contains(text(), 'What's on your mind, Myth?')]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Comment: Hello @Leo, read my comment again. I have explicitly provided two solutions, both of the, contains double quotes. In your error there is no double quote for the string.

Comment: thanks for the help @Infern0 . but sadly new problem occurs here...do you think there is possible way to click that button before posting anything? Here is the error. 

`Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="x1lliihq x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x1n2onr6" style="-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-line-clamp:2;display:-webkit-box">...</span> is not clickable at point (607, 383). Other element would receive the click: <div class="x1uvtmcs x4k7w5x x1h91t0o x1beo9mf xaigb6o x12ejxvf x3igimt xarpa2k xedcshv x1lytzrv x1t2pt76 x7ja8zs x1n2onr6 x1qrby5j x1jfb8zj" tabindex="-1">...</div>`